# read-only config values using nconf and env

Tags: node.js

I'm using [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf) to handle configuration in my app. The way I'm setting it up is as follows:

```
nconf.env({
    separator: '__',
    whitelist: ['foo', 'bar']
})
.file('config.json')
```

It appears that I'm not able to modify values if they were obtained via an environment variable. For example,

```
console.log(nconf.get()); // {"foo":123,"bar":356}
nconf.set('foo', 789);
console.log(nconf.get()); // {"foo":123,"bar":356}
```

I have inspected the `stores` attribute of `nconf` and it seems to suggest that `env` variables are read-only?

```
console.log(nconf.stores);
/**
 * { env:
 *   { type: 'env',
 *     store: { foo: [Object] },
 *     mtimes: { 'foo': 1372348332705 },
 *     readOnly: true, <-- here
 *     loadFrom: null,
 *     whitelist:
 *         ...
```

Is there a way to allow variables set via `env` variables to be modified at runtime? If I set values which were set using the `config.json` file I am able to modify values without any problems.

Any help much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this

```
nconf.stores.env.readOnly = false;
nconf.set('foo', 789);
nconf.stores.env.readOnly = true;
console.log(nconf.get()); // {"foo":789,"bar":356}
```

Hope that helps.